# Nvidia Proprietary Driver Causing Multiple Problems

Tags: xorg, nvidia, proprietary-drivers

I have recently downloaded and installed `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-319.17.run` for my Nvidia Quadro NVS 130M Graphics Card.

Installation went fine after disabling the X server and running the install from a tty.

After rebooting;

- The Slim Login manager took considerably longer to process my initial username entry (8-10 seconds vs <1s)
- Any attempts to access another tty results in a system hang, from which I have to restart.
- Attempting to launch Firefox results in a system hang before displaying anything.

I have done some searching around but have found nothing that has fixed my problem.

I am running `archbang linux x64`, so followed the instructions detailed on their site.

I am attempting `pacman -Syu` but do not think this will make much of a difference...

I changed from using the nouveau drivers.

I have looked through my  Xorg.0.log file but didn't see anything that was glaringly obvious. If you need any more details than those provided below, please comment.

Comment: Did you dowload the drivers yourself from `nvidia.com` or did you install through `pacman` ?

Comment: Nothing new to see here, move along folks.

Comment: I installed them from `nvidia.com` as I couldn't see a driver in the repos that officially supported my card.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pacman -S nvidia` to get the officially supported driver which is the same one you downloaded and you should not have any problems.

Comment: This installed fine but It ended up having exactly the same problems as before. I have opted to give up on the proprietry drivers as they are too much of a hassle to install and are not essential to the running of my computer.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC for Firefox and Nvidia you have to disable hardware acceleration in your settings. I'm actually using brave so I cannot guide you exactly through this.

I've heard that Nvidia is having trouble with `sddm` so it's probable it's also the case with `slim`.

For your TTY problem i've just posted an answer to this [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/735868/tty-disabled-when-using-nvidia-gpu-arch/738707#738707), perhaps it can help you too.