# TTY disabled when using nvidia gpu (Arch)

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, nvidia, tty, proprietary-drivers

I'm trying to figure out how to fix one of the last remaining problems with my linux installation. Everytime I install my nvidia drivers (nvidia-dkms or nvidia-open or xf86-video-nouveau) my tty are disabled and would only work if i add "nomodeset" to my kernel boot parameter. Is anyone having the same issue or had it and fixed it? 
If you need any more information please tell me.
Thx for your help

Answer (score 1):

SOOOOOOO i've been looking for an answer for about 2 weeks now and i fond it so i'm just going to write dwn here what i've done just to make sure i'll rememember it

1. do a fresh install remove any modifications you've done
2. In your `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` write this line `MODULES=(nvidia nvidia_modeset nvidia_uvm nvidia_drm)`
3. run `sudo mkinitcpio -p` (this will rebuild you images with the right module if i understood correctly)
4. DO NOT ADD `nvidia-drm.modeset=1` to your kernel options, instead add `nomodeset` that's how it worked for me. Add this in `/etc/default/grub` in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`
5. Run `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`
6. don't forget to blacklist every other gpu drivers and add

```
install i915 /usr/bin/false
install intel_agp /usr/bin/false
install viafb /usr/bin/false
install radeon /usr/bin/false
install amdgpu /usr/bin/false
```

to your blacklisted drivers or create a nw file named like this `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
7) reboot your computer

This tutorial is mainly inspired by a post made by KC_king_collin and some arch tutorial which are referenced in this post
https://forum.endeavouros.com/t/switching-to-tty-does-not-display-anything-no-signal/23807/32

Comment: Tryied to figure out this a long time ago. On Arch + RTX A4000 what made the trick, after I've had already added the same entries to the `MODULES=()` section of the image configuration, was `nomodeset` instead of `nvidia-drm.modeset=1` to the kernel parameters and also blacklisting `i915` module. Thank you for sharing this.

Comment: Anything that STARTS with "raze your system to the ground" gets an instant downvote from me.

Comment: You can still do it on a non fresh install, you just need to know exactly what the default configuration is.